# Код авторизации не берёт данные из базы данных

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Пишу форму авторизации на php. Регистрация работает, и данные заносятся в базу данных, но при входе
выводит ошибку, с учётом того, что данные верные. Хэширование пароля прописано в обоих файлах.

````
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$mysql = new mysqli('remotemysql.com','3u5SxxxWnv','password','3u5SxxxWnv');
$result=$mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `form` WHERE 'login'='$login' AND 'pass'='$pass'") ;
$user=$result->fetch_assoc();
if (count ($user)==0) {
  echo "USER NOT EXIST";
  exit;
}
$mysql->close();
header('location: /' );
?>```
````

Comment: можно узнать причём тут phpmyadmin?

Comment: Я использую базу данных phpmyadmin

Comment: Базу данных ты используешь `mysql` а `phpmyadmin` это просто интерфейс, через который ты можешь с базой общаться.

Comment: А для решения проблемы надо понять чем кавычки `'` отличаются от бэктиков `\`` и от отсутствия кавычек вообще.

Comment: Нужно посмотреть полный код, возможна ошибка связана с хешированием паролей .Каким алгоритмом хешируете пароль ?

Comment: Я пользуюсь методом хеширования md5